# C++ sequential set and get; get returns 0x0

Tags: c++, debugging

MacOS X Lion, Xcode 4
My app is a command line tool.
I have the following code in my app

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    MSystemContext * m_system = new MCommandLineContext();
    MPackageManagerNPK *packageManager = new MPackageManagerNPK();

    MEngine * engine = MEngine::getInstance();
    engine->setSystemContext(m_system); // system context
        // Strange behavior here:
    engine->setPackageManager(packageManager);
    MPackageManager *ppPackageManager = engine -> getPackageManager(); 
    engine->setPackageManager(packageManager);   //  
    engine->setPackageManager(packageManager);   //
    return 0;
}
```

I check in debugger that m_system and packageManager created and are not NULL.
I check that engine is not NULL.

```
 engine->setSystemContext(m_system);
```

works fine.
I see in debugger window that corresponding instance variable of engine is set to m_system.
I step in into the engine->setPackageManager(packageManager); and see that it works as expected. It looks like

```
void MEngine::setPackageManager(MPackageManager * packageManager)
{
   m_packageManager = packageManager;
}
```

While I'm in setPackageManager method, I see that m_packageManager variable is set to value of packageManager. 
But when debugger returns from `setPackageManager` method to `main()`, the value of m_packageManager of engine object becomes 0x0.
When I step into `getPackageManager()` , I see that m_packageManager is `0x0`.
But when after that  I step into `setPackageManager`, I see that `m_packageManager` is set to value of `packageManager`. In both cases engine object is the same.
This seems very strange to me.
App uses one thread.
App uses  dylib, which contains `MEngine` class.
What can cause such behavior?
 How can I  debug this?

**Edit:**   MEngine class (partially):

```
// .h    
class M_ENGINE_EXPORT MEngine
{
private:
...
MPackageManager * m_packageManager;
public:
MEngine(void);
...
inline MPackageManager * getPackageManager(void){ return m_packageManager; }

// .cpp

MEngine::MEngine(void):
m_packageManager(NULL)
{

}

MEngine * MEngine::getInstance(void)
{
    static MEngine m_instance;
    return &m_instance;
}
```

System context variable and its accessors defined same as packageManager variable/accessors

Comment: Could you show the definitions of `MEngine` and `getPackageManager()`?

Comment: Are you sure `MEngine::getInstance` is returning a valid pointer and not garbage?

Comment: Is this even the case when compiling with no optimisation? If the compiler has noticed you're ignoring the return value of `getPackageManager`, it might not be returning a value.

Comment: Try setting compiler to GCC instead of LLVM.  I have encountered strange things in the past with LLVM - and GCC behaved correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched build configuration from Debug  to Release, and project runs without such errors.
I think there was something with Debug settings.